# JSON response Using Volley in a recycler view in Android app

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-volley, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, android-json

I am trying to print a json response response in a recyclerview. my Recyclerview is like a expanded listView. And my json resone is like this:

```
{"Table1": 
[ 
{"filedate":"Oct 26, 2016"}, 
{"filedate":"Oct 18, 2016"} 
], 

"Table2": 
[{ 
"filedate":"Oct 18, 2016", 
"file1":"12.txt"
}, 

{ 
"filedate":"Oct 26, 2016", 
"file1":"acerinvoice.pdf" 
} 
]}
```

and I trying to print this json  resonse using this code:

```
    private void prepareListData() {

        // Volley's json array request object
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                //I think problrm is here
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {

                            **JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

                            JSONArray jsonarray = object.getJSONArray("Table1");
                            JSONArray jsonarray1 = object.getJSONArray("Table2");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                                   String str = obj.optString("filedate").trim();

                                    int lth = jsonarray1.length();


                                    data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.HEADER, str));
                               for (int j = 0; j < jsonarray1.length(); j++) {
                                        try {

                                            JSONObject obj1 = jsonarray1.getJSONObject(j);
                                            String str1 = obj1.optString("filedate").trim();

                                                data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, str1));
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**

                                            //if condition


                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
//                                            Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                        }

                                    }

                                    // adding movie to movies array



                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e("gdshfsjkg", "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }

                            }
                            Log.d("test", String.valueOf(data));
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data

                        recyclerview.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(data));
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(CLIENT, "4");
                return params;
            }
        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

ExpandableListAdapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    public static final int HEADER = 0;
    public static final int CHILD = 1;

    private List<Item> data;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(List<Item> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int type) {
        View view = null;
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        float dp = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int subItemPaddingLeft = (int) (18 * dp);
        int subItemPaddingTopAndBottom = (int) (5 * dp);
        switch (type) {
            case HEADER:
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, parent, false);
                ListHeaderViewHolder header = new ListHeaderViewHolder(view);
                return header;
            case CHILD:
                TextView itemTextView = new TextView(context);
                itemTextView.setPadding(subItemPaddingLeft, subItemPaddingTopAndBottom, 0, subItemPaddingTopAndBottom);
                itemTextView.setTextColor(0x88000000);
                itemTextView.setLayoutParams(
                        new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemTextView) {
                };
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Item item = data.get(position);
        switch (item.type) {
            case HEADER:
                final ListHeaderViewHolder itemController = (ListHeaderViewHolder) holder;
                itemController.refferalItem = item;
                itemController.header_title.setText(item.text);
                if (item.invisibleChildren == null) {
                    itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_minus);
                } else {
                    itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_plus);
                }
                itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (item.invisibleChildren == null) {
                            item.invisibleChildren = new ArrayList<Item>();
                            int count = 0;
                            int pos = data.indexOf(itemController.refferalItem);
                            while (data.size() > pos + 1 && data.get(pos + 1).type == CHILD) {
                                item.invisibleChildren.add(data.remove(pos + 1));
                                count++;
                            }
                            notifyItemRangeRemoved(pos + 1, count);
                            itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_plus);
                        } else {
                            int pos = data.indexOf(itemController.refferalItem);
                            int index = pos + 1;
                            for (Item i : item.invisibleChildren) {
                                data.add(index, i);
                                index++;
                            }
                            notifyItemRangeInserted(pos + 1, index - pos - 1);
                            itemController.btn_expand_toggle.setImageResource(R.drawable.circle_minus);
                            item.invisibleChildren = null;
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;
            case CHILD:
                TextView itemTextView = (TextView) holder.itemView;
                itemTextView.setText(data.get(position).text);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return data.get(position).type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    private static class ListHeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView header_title;
        public ImageView btn_expand_toggle;
        public Item refferalItem;

        public ListHeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            header_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.header_title);
            btn_expand_toggle = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_expand_toggle);
        }
    }

    public static class Item {
        public int type;
        public String text;
        public List<Item> invisibleChildren;

        public Item() {
        }

        public Item(int type, String text) {
            this.type = type;
            this.text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

But this code print nothing in my recycler UI.It show only a empty layout.I have also tried to print the response in my log and it prints whole response together.**I want to print table1 contents in headers and table2 contents in as child(items) with their respective headers**.how to do this?If any other information needed please ask..

Comment: does it print something in stacktrace in logcat? Also have you tried debugging step by step?

Comment: Yes..t it prints the complete response only..

Comment: Below is the right json format, please use this , it should work- {"Table1": 
[ 
{"filedate":"Oct 26, 2016"}, 
{"filedate":"Oct 18, 2016"} 
], 
"Table2": 
[{"filedate":"Oct 18, 2016", "file1":"12.txt" },
{"filedate":"Oct 26, 2016", "file1":"acerinvoice.pdf"} 
]}

Comment: THis is just a sample.. there is some suyntax error ..I have updated this..I have have already getting the complete response in my log.

Comment: you are looping inside another loop, "table2" in not inside "table1".... hope you understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my problem to just change above code like this..

```
     private void prepareListData() {


        // Volley's json array request object
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {


                        JSONObject object = null;
                        try {
                            object = new JSONObject(response);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        JSONArray jsonarray = null;
                        JSONArray jsonarray1 = null;
                        try {
                            jsonarray = object.getJSONArray("Table1");
                            jsonarray1 = object.getJSONArray("Table1");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
//                            
                                String str = obj.optString("filedate").trim();


                                Log.d("test", str);

                                data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.HEADER, str));

//                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonarray1.length(); j++) {

                                        try {

                                            JSONObject obj1 = jsonarray1.getJSONObject(j);
                                            String str1 = obj1.optString("filedate").trim();
                                            String str3 = obj1.optString("category").trim();
                                            String str2 = obj1.optString("file1").trim();

                                            String str4 = obj1.optString("4").trim();
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "server data respone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test"+str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            if (str == str1) {
//                                                data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, str1));
                                                data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, str3));
                                                data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, str2));

                                            }
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            //if condition


                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
//                                            Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                        }

                                    }

                                // adding movie to movies array



                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e("gdshfsjkg", "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }

                        }
                        Log.d("test", String.valueOf(data));




                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
//                        adapterheader.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        recyclerview.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(data));
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
//                hidePDialog();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(CLIENT, "4");
                return params;
            }
        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably check your response first of everything. As per your requirements you should use HashMap and ArrayList. Follow these following steps:

1.Take a ArrayLsit and store child data of 1st heading and so on with index starting from 0.
2.Store headers in HashMap as key.

`ex: HashMap<String,ArrayList<Data>> hm;
 hm.put("your first heading string","related arraylist")`;

Then use ExpandableListView to arrange parent and child items.

Comment: refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: I have updated my adapter class in question....I hope it is near about about same as U explain..

Answer (score 0):

please check your json response this is invalid json response first try to validate your json formate after try to decode and add in recycler view.

Comment: I have already know that this is  somwe way wrong..And I'm also trying some other thing..I want to know what is correct..

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Response into Logcat also the Exception. I've tested the Response you've supplied that contains some unnecessary "," that may cause the Exception.[image]

Comment: This is just a sample.. there is some suyntax error ..I have updated this..I have have already getting the complete response in my log.

Comment: Then Debug each line of your Code (the array size, the JSONObject ..etc). Try Log or Debug .. hope you'll find out the problem.

Comment: the problem is in printing table2(i.e. child item). Can U please help?